# Shell script to install and configure SFTP server on Ubuntu is broken

Tags: shell

I'm trying to create a shell script to automate setup of an SFTP server, but I've run into some problems as noted in the code.

```
#!/bin/bash

sftp_user='sftpuser'
sftp_passwd='SomePassword'

print_success() { echo -e "\e[32m${@}\e[0m"; }
print_error() { echo -e "\e[31m${@}\e[0m"; }

if [ `whoami` != "root" ] && [ `whoami` != "forge" ] && [ `whoami` != "homestead" ] && [ `whoami` != "vagrant" ];
then
    print_error "You must be root to run this script"
    exit 1
fi

# PROBLEM #1 The IF below doesn't correctly detect when apt is updated. Always says failed.
echo "Updating apt"
sudo apt-get update 2>&1
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    print_success "Updated apt"
else
    print_error "Failed to update apt"
    exit 1
fi

echo "Installing VsFTPD package"
sudo apt-get -y install vsftpd 2>&1
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    print_success "Installed VsFTPD"
else
    print_error "Failed to Install VsFTPD"
    exit 1
fi

# PROBLEM #2 The conditional below does not detect if openssh server already installed and up to date.
echo "Installing openssh-server"
sudo apt-get install openssh-server 2>&1
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
    print_success "Installed openssh-server"
else
    print_error "Failed to Install openssh-server"
    exit 1
fi

sshd_config='/etc/ssh/sshd_config'

sudo mv $sshd_config $sshd_config.bak
sudo rm -f $sshd_config

echo "# SSH Config
Port 22
Protocol 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin without-password
StrictModes yes
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
IgnoreRhosts yes
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
HostbasedAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
UsePAM yes
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match group ftpaccess
ChrootDirectory %h
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
" | sudo tee $sshd_config

echo "Restarting SSH service"
sudo service ssh restart

echo "Creating user and group"
sudo groupadd ftpaccess
sudo useradd -m $sftp_user -g ftpaccess -s /usr/sbin/nologin
echo "$sftp_passwd" | sudo passwd $sftp_user

echo "Done"
```

I'm no pro at making shell scripts, so it's quite possible I missed something else, too. Any ideas?

Code is based on:
http://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/setup-ftp-server-on-ubuntu-14-04-vsftpd/

**EDIT:** *The updated script with all fixes in case anyone is interested:*

```
#!/bin/bash

# Based on: http://www.krizna.com/ubuntu/setup-ftp-server-on-ubuntu-14-04-vsftpd/
sftp_user='someuser'
sftp_passwd='SomePassword'

# IMPORTANT: Edit the values above or comment out the user add code before running.

print_success() { echo -e "\e[32m${@}\e[0m"; }
print_error() { echo -e "\e[31m${@}\e[0m"; }

if [ `whoami` != "root" ] && [ `whoami` != "forge" ] && [ `whoami` != "homestead" ] && [ `whoami` != "vagrant" ];
then
    print_error "You must be root to run this script!"
    exit 1
fi

echo "Updating apt..."
sudo_output=$(sudo bash -c "apt-get update 2>&1; echo $?")
sudo_result=$?
aptget_result=$(echo "${sudo_output}"| tail -1)

echo "${sudo_output}"

# Check results
if [ ${sudo_result} -eq 0 ]; then
    if [ ${aptget_result} -eq 0 ]; then
       print_success "Updated apt."
    else
       print_error "Failed to apt, apt-get error!"
    fi
else
    print_error "Failed to update apt, sudo error!"
    exit 1
fi

echo "Installing VsFTPD package..."
sudo_output=$(sudo bash -c "apt-get -y install vsftpd 2>&1; echo $?")

# Get results.
sudo_result=$?
aptget_result=$(echo "${sudo_output}"| tail -1)

# Show apt-get output.
echo "${sudo_output}"

# Check results
if [ ${sudo_result} -eq 0 ]; then
    if [ ${aptget_result} -eq 0 ]; then
       print_success "Installed VsFTPD."
    else
       print_error "Failed to Install VsFTPD, apt-get error!"
    fi
else
    print_error "Failed to Install VsFTPD, sudo error!"
    exit 1
fi

echo "Installing openssh-server"
sudo_output=$(sudo bash -c "apt-get install openssh-server 2>&1; echo $?")
sudo_result=$?
aptget_result=$(echo "${sudo_output}"| tail -1)
echo "${sudo_output}"

# Check results
if [ ${sudo_result} -eq 0 ]; then
    if [ ${aptget_result} -eq 0 ]; then
       print_success "Installed openssh-server."
    else
       print_error "Failed to install openssh-server, apt-get error!"
    fi
else
    print_error "Failed to install openssh-server, sudo error!"
    exit 1
fi

sshd_config='/etc/ssh/sshd_config'

sudo mv $sshd_config $sshd_config.bak
sudo rm -f $sshd_config

echo "# SSH Config
Port 22
Protocol 2
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
UsePrivilegeSeparation yes
KeyRegenerationInterval 3600
ServerKeyBits 1024
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel INFO
LoginGraceTime 120
PermitRootLogin without-password
StrictModes yes
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
IgnoreRhosts yes
RhostsRSAAuthentication no
HostbasedAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
PrintMotd no
PrintLastLog yes
TCPKeepAlive yes
AcceptEnv LANG LC_*
UsePAM yes
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match group ftpaccess
ChrootDirectory %h
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
" | sudo tee $sshd_config

echo "Restarting SSH service..."
sudo service ssh restart

echo "Creating user and group..."
sudo groupadd ftpaccess
sudo useradd -m $sftp_user -g ftpaccess -s /usr/sbin/nologin
echo "$sftp_passwd" | sudo passwd $sftp_user

echo "Done! :)"
```

Comment: An interesting problem and good question. Not sure, does `sudo` return the `$?` of the program it invokes, or does it return an `$?` to indicate 'hey, I did my job! (or not)' ? `sudo true` and `sudo false` might show that to you. Good luck.

Comment: Everywhere in 'IF' condition you used return value `$?`, so first you need to  understand return value. In simplest way if your code executed successfully it will return `0` else any other value. Thus you need to replace `-ne` with `-eq` as per your code.

Comment: FYI, the `echo -e` behavior this script expects contravenes the POSIX standard, which doesn't allow it to do anything other than print the literal string `-e` (followed by other arguments, with backslash-sequences expanded, or not, exactly as they would be without the `-e` depending on whether the system supports XSI extensions). See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/echo.html, particularly including the APPLICATION USAGE section, and consider using `printf` instead in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! Educational for further shell script comprehension. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking the return value of sudo, not the return value of apt-get.

EDIT:
`sudo "whoami; whoami"` will return  an error, you need `sudo bash -c 'whoami; whoami'`. The solution was without bash -c, I changed this.
Note: Perhaps the whole construction is not needed, `sudo true; echo $?; sudo false; echo $?` returns 0 and 1 on my server. Can you check the output of your sudo command?

When you want to check both:

```
sudo_output=$(sudo bash -c "apt-get -y install vsftpd 2>&1; echo $?")
# Get results
sudo_result=$?
aptget_result=$(echo "${sudo_output}"| tail -1)
# Show apt-get output
echo "${sudo_output}"

# check results

if [ ${sudo_result} -eq 0 ]; then
    if [ ${aptget_result} -eq 0 ]; then
       print_success "Installed VsFTPD"
    else
       print_error "Failed to Install VsFTPD, apt-get error"
    fi
else
    print_error "Failed to Install VsFTPD, sudo error"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: in ksh,  my sudo_output shows  `sudo: apt-get -y install vsftpd ; echo 0: command not found` (which is kind of what I expected). Does that really work for you? What OS and shell? but, I like the idea, I use `apstat=$(apt-get ...;eval echo \$?) ` to get the return code directly. Good luck.

Comment: I did not have a shell when I wrote the answer. I checked and improved my answer, but your suggestion of  `sudo true` and `sudo false` shows that sudo passes through the returnvalue of the command it called.

Comment: Glad if that helped. Good luck to all.

Comment: I also get 0 and 1 for `sudo true; echo $?; sudo false; echo $?` and your modifications fixed the installation detection issues. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps this should entirely remove old/inaccurate information, rather than only editing in corrected content, to have less risk of being misleading to folks who only skim?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I want to remove the old info, but I do not understand why the original script of the OP failed. He accepted the work-around with the echo $?, but sudo false return 1. Perhaps he needed the bash -c? The long solution can be helpful for a skimmer with a similar  ssh-problem.

Comment: Frankly, I simply disbelieve the OP's claim that the original script failed in the manner given with no content on stderr explaining the failure. There hasn't been enough info given by the OP to prove the claim (much less a standalone reproducer outside the context of a script nobody else has the environment/setup to run), and the claimed behavior is simply contrary to how `bash` and `sudo` behave. People asking questions here without combing through their scripts' stderr feeds first and including relevant data isn't exactly unheard of.